# reference to account not found in query result sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx, opportunity, account, contact, salesforcedx-cli

I am running the following `sfdx` command to export Accounts, Contacts, and Opportunities. However, I am running into the following error messages below.

**Question:**

1. How can I export the Accounts, Contacts, and Opportunities using `sfdx force:data:tree:export`?

**What I tried:**

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -u myenv -q myfolder/account-query -d myfolder/accounts --prefix data-export --outputdir myfolder/accounts/ --plan
```

**Error message:**

> Opportunity reference to account (someid) not found in query results

**account-query file content**

```
Select Id, Name, myfield__c \
,(Select Id, FirstName, LastName From Contacts) \
,(Select Id, Name From Opportunities where isClosed = false) \
From Account Where myfield__c != null Limit 200
```

Comment: The query looks fine. Would you be run a test by removing the custom field and where clause. Just the standard fields in query

Comment: @manjit5190 it doesn't work without the where clause. I found the only workaround was to reduce the `limit 200` down to `limit 50`. Something weird going on where the related objects (have an account id lookup) are not included in the account query doesn't work. Its the only thing I can think of but that didn't make sense to me